# What is the Quickest Way Of MongoDB Collection Sorting in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'll keep this short. Have 31k documents and need to sort them by a specific number field's value. Takes up to 5 seconds with the following code. Looking for a faster way.

(Context: Making a discord bot with a 'leaderboards' function which, when called, displays a leaderboard of users ranked by their total experience which is what I'm sorting them by. The ranks shift constantly hence working with a pre-sorted collection is out of the question.)

I have tried the standard method i.e `db.collection.find().sort(whatIWannaSortBy)` as shown

```
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/databaseName', {
        useNewUrlParser: true
    });

    mySchema.find().sort([['EXPERIENCE', 'descending']]).exec((err, res) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        // res is the sorted result
        // Code to display the result goes here
    });
```

I know there's a faster way since I've seen people with larger databases retrieving sorted data faster than me. I don't know if it's because they use the mongo shell and are not doing it in Node.js like me.

Answer (score 1):

Add indexes on the field you want to sort. It will improve your performance significantly.

```
mySchema.index({field1: 1});
```

Comment: The values by which I wanna sort shift constantly tho so Indexing won't work?

Comment: No , I dont think constant shifting will have effect on your sorting time.

Comment: What I mean is, won't I have to constantly keep re-indexing the data? For example, if 'a' had a value of '12' and 'b' had a value of '13', and the next day 'a' had the value of 14, won't the indexes be thrown out of order?

Comment: no, you wont have to constantly re-index data as updating an indexed field in mongodb causes an update of the index.

Comment: Apparently the data was already indexed before, meaning it was taking 5 seconds to sort indexed data. Does there exist any other quicker way?

Comment: @vSpecky indexing by the field to be sorted as mentioned by Krishna _is_ the quickest way, and it works like Krishna described. What do you actually mean by "the values is shifting constantly"?